# How to let @font-face work in Firefox using Weebly

Tags: font-face, weebly

I've succesfully used the @font-face rule to use a font on my Weebly website. That is... in Chrome, not Firefox. I've found the 'hack' to use a .htaccess file. But Weebly doesn't allow to add a .htaccess file. So I'm back to square one... Any tips, anyone?

http://www.ziehaar.nl

Comment: looks exactly the same both in FF and Chrome, not sure what are you asking. Where are those fonts supposed to be applied?

Comment: @Fabio The heading should be FilmotypeBrooklyn. It's the same font as in the logo 'get in the picture'. In Firefox it looks like Times.

Comment: Anita, I took a screen-shot in both Chrome and FF and they look the same, exception made that I'm not seeing that Newsletter opt-in box in FF, but fonts are the same, so it's possible that you're seeing a cached version in Chrome. See screen-shot at http://i60.tinypic.com/voq6gk.jpg . Anyways, for your problem, see answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your font rendering in Firefox comes from permission directives. For security reasons, Firefox has a set of directives for font-face that includes the dreaded **["Same Origin Policy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)** restriction, which means your fonts have to be served from the same domain the page resides at. So, with that in mind, we can have the easiest solution:

**Solution #1**

host your fonts at *www.ziehaar.nl* (and warning: depending on the `.htaccess` file you have in your site, the www. part will make a difference, meaning that you might be able to see the font if you type *www.ziehaar.nl* yet not see it if you type *ziehaar.nl*

**Solution #2**
Host the fonts elsewhere, and take a look at [this thread at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) on ways to circumvent the **"same origin policy"** rule.

**Solution #3**
Add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|woff|ttf)$">
  SetEnvIf Origin »
    "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(weebly\.com|ziehaar\.nl)$" origin_is=$0
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch>
```

Depending on your skills you may try to use different solution until it works, but just for the sake of it and to show everything other than cross-domain policies are fine, take a look at the image below:

[image: ff fonts example]

As you may see, I'm seeing your fonts correctly in Firefox after testing. That's because I loaded your font files and now they're in my Firefox cache , hence the cross-domain isn't affecting the rendering of those fonts.

Anyways, hope this helps, just let us know how it goes